# Distinct between file and folder with same name aws s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I seem not to understand how this works.

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
s3:/bucket1/file1
s3:/bucket1/file2
s3:/bucket1/dir1/file3
s3:/bucket1/dir1/file4
```

Now when I want to list all content (including "directories" e.g dir1) I can do:

```
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName("bucket1")
            .withPrefix("")
            .withDelimiter("/");

    return awsS3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
```

Here Objectsummaries contains file1 and file2, common prefixes contains dir1

and for listing content of /bucket1/dir1 I could do

```
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName("bucket1")
            .withPrefix("dir1/")
            .withDelimiter("/");

    return awsS3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
```

Now if I wanted to check if some folder exists I can do:

```
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName("bucket1")
            .withPrefix("dir1/")
            .withDelimiter("/");

    return awsS3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest).getObjectSummiaries().size() > 0;
```

Here I check if exactly one object was found.

And I want to check if some file exists:

```
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName("bucket1")
            .withPrefix("file1")
            .withDelimiter("/");
    return awsS3Client.listObjects(listObjectRequest).getObjectSummaries().size() == 1
```

But my question is, to simulate directory, we put object with empty content in it and with "/" at the end, and that means I can have file and directory with same name. In that case, how would I distinguish it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple objects with the same key.

This means that the latest content that you add with a given key wins. It is impossible to have a confusion between a "folder" and a "file" with the same name.

There is no concept of folders in S3 actually, the console just gives us that impression because of how file systems works. It is better if you think about S3 as a key/value pair database.

Comment: i just tested it, i created file with "file1" name and then put empty file with "file1/" and the second one is displayed as folder in aws s3 console so while the second one has "/" in name, it looks the same visually in console